# Problem on distributive lattices

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

I'm trying to prove the following:
 Show that a lattice is distributive if and only if it does not contain a sublattice isomorphic to either of the two lattices below.

[image]

I was able to prove that neither of these two lattices are distributive. Then  showed the forward direction, which is as follows (proved by the contrapositive):

Let $D$ be a lattice. Suppose there is some $L\subseteq D$ such that $L\cong A$ or $L\cong B$. Then by our previous argument (above), $D$ would contain at least three elements that do not satisfy the distributive property. Hence, $D$ is not a distributive lattice.

I can't figure out how to get the converse! I started with (contrapositive approach): Suppose $D$ is a lattice, but it is not distributive. Then there exist $x,y,z\in D$ such that either $x\wedge (y\vee z)>(x\wedge y)\vee (x\wedge z)$ or $x\wedge (y\vee z)<(x\wedge y)\vee (x\wedge z)$.

I can't figure out how to show that $D$ will have a sublattice isomorphic to one of the lattices above. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can find proof in the book "Lattices and Ordered Algebraic Structures" by T. S. Blyth

Comment: [This PDF](http://www.tau.ac.il/~landman/Online_Class_Notes_file/Boolean/2%20Distributive%20lattices.pdf) has half of the proof: it has a proof that every distributive lattice is modular, and that a lattice is modular iff the pentagon cannot be embedded in it.